# Find the Layout virtual path of any particular View/Action

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

In ASP.NET MVC, can I get access dynamically to the VirtualPath of the Layout file chosen by the view. For example, in the view of an action "Index" I would like to get the Layout being used by another action view.

Something like this would be nice:

```
@SomeHelper.Layout("Action","Controller")
```

Ideally, the above call will return a string like `"~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"`

Comment: Not sure if I'm following what you need. Can you clarify what's the difference between what you need and `Html.Action`?

Comment: @tweray `@Html.Action` executes the action and renders the html on the page. What I want is the string value of the virtual path of the layout file used by that action (example: "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml")